# Optimizing a stability function that has no closed form

Tags: optimization, closed-form

Let's assume I have function $\mathbf F(h)$ that has the scalar $h$ as an input and a matrix as an output. I define the distance between two matrices

$$
\mathbf A = \mathbf F(h_1) \\
\mathbf B = \mathbf F(h_2)
$$

where A and B have the same shape as

$$
dist(\mathbf A, \mathbf B) =
  \sum_i
  \frac{
     \mathbf {A_i} \cdot \mathbf {B_i}
  }{
     \|\mathbf {A_i} \| \cdot \|\mathbf {B_i} \|
  } 
$$

where $i$ is the row for $A$ and $B$ respective.

Next I can define a stability $s$ in respect to $h$ with

$$
s(h) = \frac {  dist(\mathbf F(h_1), \mathbf F(h_2))  } {   h_2 - h_1  }
\text{ for }
h_2 \rightarrow h
\text{ and }
h_1 \rightarrow h
$$

where $h_1 < h < h_2$ and $h-h_1 = h_2 - h$.

I want to find the $h$ which results in the highest stability, so I want to find the maximum of $s(h)$.

The main issue is the not-so-closed form of the definition of the stability $s(h)$. 
A side issue is that calculating any $\mathbf F(h)$ is very expensive.

What is the best way to find the $h$ which results in the highest stability?